# How do you perform a filtered database lookup in views?

Tags: django

I'm working with a database in Django. I'm familiar with the Django database API but am wondering how to interact with the data base inside `views.py`. Here's the relevant model:

```
class SlotFilling(models.Model):
    originator = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    empty_slot = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I'm trying to write an `If` statment in my program to check if `empty_slot` is `True` for a given `originator`. I'm thinking I might be able to use `filter()` to accomplish this. Any experience with the most efficient way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to query for originator all empty slots you can do something as following

```
SlotFilling.objects.filter(empty_slot=True, originator='someoriginator')
```

@comment code

Assuming originator is unique

```
originator_slot = SlotFlling.objects.get(originator='originator')
slot_value = originator_slot.empty_slot
```

You can use filter instead if originator is not unique, which would list you back all rows for particular originator

```
originator_slots = SlotFlling.objects.filter(originator='originator')

for originator_slot in originator_slots:
    print originator_slot.empty_slot
```

Also please check out  [retrieving objects in DB API documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) as saying that you are familiar with it would be big overstatement :)